# How do I manage a private gallery in vs 2017 using registry like I did in vs 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

How to: Manage a Private Gallery By Using Registry Settings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266735.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The above article details how I am doing it in 2015 by modifying the registry but the problem is that VS does not store this info in the registry anymore (I don't think so). It used to be in the ExtensionManager folder in vs 2015 ([HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ExtensionManager\Repositories...) but that folder no longer exists (along with 30 or so others that are missing).

Supposedly VS stores them in a private registry now:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/breaking-changes-2017#visual-studio-registry

I don't understand if I will be able to use the registry in the same way as before and if not, what is the recommendation for the easiest way to do that...basically we use the registry to install our private VS extension gallery into developers machines by simply clicking a .reg file so they don't have to set that up themselves...actually same same as what this answer says: [Programmatically specify Private Extension Gallery in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524606/programmatically-specify-private-extension-gallery-in-visual-studio-2012#answer-14593071)

I'd rather not create an atom feed but if thats the last resort then i'm all ears.

Thanks